# Web-Based Open Source Inventory Management App?

Tags: gratis, open-source, inventory

Do you know any good Inventory Management Apps? The features I need are not that complex or anything, we just need a way to keep track of the status of the tools we use in our company. Freeware is welcome but Open Source is preferred. Thank you.

Comment: NASA uses MediaWiki for this! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Testimonials#NASA

Answer (score 1):

[Openbravo](http://www.openbravo.com/) is one of the leading open source ERP tools available. Within Openbravo is a powerful inventory tool that keeps your product flowing and ties in directly to every aspect of your ERP solution. Not only can you manage your vendors, you can track where the inventory moves (between warehouses and/or clients/customers) and much more. OpenBravo can even help you accelerate new product introduction.

[PartKeepr](http://partkeepr.org/) is a niche tool for tracking and managing inventory of electronic components. It's a much smaller tool and it doesn't include a full CRM or ERP. But it will do wonders for those of you looking to keep track of electronic parts. It's simple to install (written in PHP 5.3 and JavaScript) and does make use of a database (MySQL).

> Disclamer - text copied from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-top-apps-for-managing-inventory/)